# what does the void ** mean

Tags: c, void-pointers

I haven’t seen the void ** previously in the C language course.

```
int *dev_c;
dev_c = &val;
printf("%p\n",dev_c);  // val address
printf("%p\n",&dev_c); // get the address of dev_c
printf("%p\n",(void **)&dev_c);
```

is **(void **)** a type converter? the last two lines output the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(void**)` is a cast. It's casting the `&dev_c` address (which has the type pointer to pointer to `int`), making it a pointer to a pointer to `void` instead.

Comment: (void **)&dev_c == (void *) dev_c?

Comment: @John: No, `(void **)&dev_c` is the *address* of the `dev_c` variable on the stack. `(void *)dev_c` is the *value* stored in the `dev_c` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer to a pointer of void type.  That line is casting a reference to that type.

Answer (score 1):

`void**` is pointer to a pointer.In you example `dev_c` is pointer so address of this `&dev_c` will be a pointer to pointer and this is typecasted to `void**`.

Answer (score 0):

`(void **)` is a type cast to indicate a pointer to a pointer.

In your example code of printf it does nothing.